# Sed to replace specific string, in multiple lines which are between some pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I have a simple question (I think), I need to replace a specific string which occurs in multiple lines in a file (verilog). These lines are themselves between specific patterns

ex:

```
lk
lk
lk
lk
lk

//comment1
input [5:0]a,
input [3:0]b,
input c,
input [4:0]d,
input f,

//comment2
lm
lm
lm
lm
```

I need to replace "input" with "logic" between "comment1" and "comment2" keeping them as it is in the final result (quotes not included, only for understanding)

Right now what I have is

```
sed '/\/comment1/,/\/comment2/s/input/logic/g' file1.sv > file2.sv
```

the result I get is

```
lk
lk
lk
lk
lk

//comment1
logic
logic
logic
logic
logic

//comment2
lm
lm
lm
lm
```

The rest of the text after logic is gone, I need to preserve that

Can someone please help, I will be grateful...

Comment: I can't reproduce the error-- your solution seems to work perfectly. What version of sed are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sed command:

```
sed -i.bak '/\/\/comment1/,/\/\/comment2/s/\<input\>/logic/g' file
```

- `/\/\/comment1/,/\/\/comment2/` is to search text between 2 comment blocks
- `\<input\>` is for matching input with word boundaries
- `s/\<input\>/logic/g` is for replacing "input" with "logic"

Comment: Thank you very very much, your solution was perfect.
I am grateful
I did not use -i.bak, could you also tell me what that is?

Comment: `-i.bak` is for inline editing of file with `.bak` is the extension of the backup file which gets created before editing the file by sed.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested your sed command, and to me it worked out just perfect. The only thing I can see that is wrong is that you have forgotten the last slash in front of the comment-lines. It worked for me either way, but the correct line would be

```
sed '/\/\/comment1/,/\/\/comment2/s/input/logic/g' file1.sv > file2.sv
```

As you can see I have one more "/" in each of the comment-lines. Try it out and see if it helps.
I am running GNU sed version 4.2.1 here.

To answer your question in the comment about reading the filename from the command line inside a script this would be the most simple way

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '/\/\/comment1/,/\/\/comment2/s/input/logic/g' "$1" > file2.sv
exit 0
```

$1 means the first argument. If would like to be able to specifiy the output file as well you do as this

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '/\/\/comment1/,/\/\/comment2/s/input/logic/g' "$1" > "$2"
exit 0
```

Whereas this means the first argument is the input file, the second argument is the output file.
The quotation might not be necessary, but it's a good idea to quote strings (and the filenames are strings basically).

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right. 
do you happen to know how I can make this script, such that it takes an input file in the command line?
Your help will be greatly appreciated.